# Splitting a line into two in OpenLayers

Tags: postgis, openlayers, wfs

I have some WFS layers in OpenLayers, containing lines. I try to make a tool to split these lines and add a symbol in the breakpoint. Then save them to a PostGIS database. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to serve your data in transactional WFS, [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html) is a good example for that. You need to create you own "SplitLine" control, and implement the split logic there.

Comment: Thanks. I found OpenLayers.Control.Split method. [exmaple](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/split-feature.html).

Comment: Great! Didn't know there's a split control in openlayers.